# Rails, Bootstrap Modal, trigger code on modal open

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using the Readable Gem, and have comments in a modal. I want to mark a comment as read only when the user opens up the Bootstrap modal. Can someone point me in the right direction to trigger the comment as read ONLY when the user opens up the modal? Currently, it marks the comment as read before the modal is even open because I believe it is running the code without user opening the modal.

```
<script>
  $(('#picModal-<%= index %>').hasClass('show'), function(){
    "<% comment.mark_as_read! for: current_user %>";
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the on show event of the modal, like

`$('##picModal-<%= index %>').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  "<% comment.mark_as_read! for: current_user %>";
  //do something else!
})`

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a CommentsController.
In the update action set the comment.mark_as_read!

```
$('#picModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){
      // Set ajax patch to the 'comments#update' with the comment id
    })
```

This event fires went the modal shown

Comment: I have read the docs... I'm just not sure where the error is... with my code in my original post, the  "<% comment.mark_as_read! for: current_user %>"; fires even if the modal is not open... that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: I guess this is done went the entire page is rendered. I would suggest to create an endpoint for ajax update and do it from the event block via ajax.